# Code-Point Polygon Data and Google Maps

Tags: point, postal-code

I'm currently working with OS Code-point polygons and google maps coordinates. I have google maps point coordinates for a list of houses which are located at the center of each full postcode (according to google maps) they correspond to. The code-point polygon OS data has polygons for each full postcode marking their boundaries, but also has a fair few (5%-ish) small polygons, called "vertical streets" - small areas (usually tall buildings) within other post code polygons which have more than one postcode assigned to them. These each have a reference number and separate look-up table which gives the (usually) 2-3 postcodes that are assigned to that building.

How can I try and assign a postcode in buildings that fall in the vertical streets, given that I don't have a full address (only street name) for these properties?

I have checked online and can't find any indication of how this can be dealt with. Google maps postcode data is not the most accurate either - I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it very much depends on how you want to use the data and the level of accuracy required. Without the full address it is going to be difficult for you to work out which vertical street postcode to assign (if at all), but then if all you have is the street name then one could argue that you don't necessarily need to concern yourself with selecting the correct vertical street postcode.

In your situation I would simply select the first postcode in the lookup table for the vertical street the point falls within. Street name and any of the postcodes falling along it would be sufficient when you don't have the full address. Otherwise you could end up wasting a lot of time trying to find a clever way to select the correct vertical street postcode.

Comment: You've made a very good point there. You've made me think about what I'm trying to achieve a little more - thanks!